# Create Excel with OpenXML does not Open File

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, excel, openxml

I am using OpenXML to create an Excel document in my MVC application.  As far as the code goes, I think I'm doing everything correctly.

C#

```
public FileResult GetExcelReport()
{
    // Build dataset
    var excelStream = CreateSpreadsheet(data);
    return new FileStreamResult(excelStream, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet); 
}

internal MemoryStream CreateSpreadsheet(DataSet data)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    SpreadsheetDocument ssDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    // do some stuff to make a spreadsheet

    ssDoc.Close();
    return stream;
}
```

JS

```
function createExcelReport(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Remote/GetExcelReport",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            sData: // params for report
        },
        success: function(data){
            window.location.href = "/Page/Index"
        }, error: function(error){
        }
    });
}
```

I am wanting the file to open in the browser without it actually downloading/saving.  The process seems like it's working, but the file doesn't open.

If I change

```
SpreadsheetDocument ssDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
```

to

```
SpreadsheetDocument ssDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("filename.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
```

(to use a filename instead of a memory stream), everything works fine and it saves to my hard drive, but then I have to navigate to the location to open the file.

Any thoughts as to what I may be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I solved my problem.  My AJAX wasn't doing anything with the response, so instead of an AJAX call, I used a @Url.Action link --

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetExcelReport","Remote")">Report</a>
```